# Changing focus to app started with Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, uac

I use the method of Task Scheduler to start apps with admin privileges via shortcut to bypass the UAC.

How ever, I cannot seem to make it switch focus to the started app. It used to be that case in Win 7 when ever I started such link.

How can I make it to work again? Before you suggest it: No, I'm not turning off UAC.

Comment: One way that seems to bypass UAC and still set focus is to set the task to run `C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe` with the arguments `/c start "" "<path to exe>"` rather than calling the program directly

Comment: It's not just to bypass UAC, but to start them in admin mode. But I'll try this method.

Comment: It's a good method to bypass UAC if one does not need the admin mode, for admin mode, that's no good. But thanks, I could use that too!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about admin mode? If you are trying to run a task interactively as a different user, I don't think this is possible anymore,  see https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7