# Can I configure KeePass to prompt for master key/password on Windows restore?

Tags: windows, automation, keepass

I have configured [KeePass](https://keepass.info/index.html) to *Lock workspace when computer is about to be suspended* (under *Options→Security*), which ensures my passwords are protected when my Windows 7 system sleeps or hibernates.  But each time I restore my system from sleep or hibernation, my passwords are consequently locked and I must right-click KeePass' tray icon, select *Unlock Workspace*, and enter my database master key.

Is there a way to have KeePass prompt for my key automatically in this situation?

Answer (score 14):

(I [answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)):

I can find no way to configure KeePass itself to *Prompt for master password when restored*, so here is a workaround based on [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/q/276054/460302):

Create and save a new Windows *Scheduled Task*:

1. Start Task Scheduler: <kbd>Win</kbd>→*Administrative
   Tools→Task Scheduler*, or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter
   `taskschd.msc`
2. In Task Scheduler, *Action→Create Task*
3. In Create Task's *General* tab, name the task *Run KeePass at unlock*
4. In Create Task's *Triggers* tab, click <kbd>New...</kbd> then for *Begin the task:* select <kbd>On 
   workstation unlock</kbd> and click <kbd>OK</kbd>
5. In Create Task's *Actions* tab, click <kbd>New...</kbd> then in the *Program/script* field enter `"C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe"` and in the *Add arguments (optional)* field enter `/c start "" <location of your KeePass database file>` (the location of your KeePass database file appears in KeePass' main window title).
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in Create Task to save the task, then close the Task Scheduler window.

Now when you unlock your system, Task Scheduler will execute KeePass, which will [gain focus](https://superuser.com/q/1315217/460302) and prompt you for your Master Password.  If you have KeePass configured to *Minimize main window after opening a database* (under *Options→Interface*), your KeePass windows will also minimize after you have successfully entered your Master Password.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you can't enter the path to KeePass in the Program/script field directly, instead of as an argument to `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @KodosJohnson, initially I entered the path as you describe.  That caused KeePass to prompt me when I restored my Windows, but KeePass' prompt did not have focus, so I needed to click on the Master Password input field before typing.  The use of `cmd.exe` eliminates this need.

Comment: Perhaps this could be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988863/using-command-line-batch-to-switch-to-focus-on-app. Also, maybe you need to add a delay somehow in the scheduled task.

Comment: @KodosJohnson, thank you.  I considered sendKeys.bat but want to keep this solution as simple as possible.  The latest revision (pointing `start` to the location of my KeePass database) seems to work reliably so I've updated my answer with it.  Please let me know if there are any problems with this approach.