# how to make a bat file that starts a file at specific time without task scheduler

Tags: backup

I've created a .bat file that backups my files, but I want to create another .bat file that can run my first program as administrator on schedule (without using task scheduler). I don't want to use the task scheduler because it doesn't run the program as an administrator.

Comment: " I don't want to use the task scheduler because it doesn't run the program as an administrator." See this....https://superuser.com/questions/770420/schedule-a-task-with-admin-privileges-without-a-user-prompt-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Check the box that says it should run with highest privileges and it will run with administrative privileges. You could use the `at` command but either way it would mean you'd have to have a cmd constantly open.